# Why is this query asking for a parameter value?

Tags: sql, parameters, ms-access-2010

I'm working in Access 2010.  I have the following query (which is named bird_year_species):

```
SELECT sub.Species, Min(sub.obs_year) AS First_sighting_year
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Genus_BiLE] & " " & [Species_BiLE] AS Species, [Year_BiLE] AS  obs_year
FROM BiLE_Bound


UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT [Genus_BiMN] & " " & [Species_BiMN] AS Species, [Year_BiMN] AS obs_year
FROM BiMN_Bound

UNION ALL 

SELECT DISTINCT [Genus_BiPC] & " " & [Species_BiPC] AS Species, [Year_BiPC] AS obs_year
FROM BiPC_Bound

UNION ALL

SELECT Distinct [Genus_BiOP] & " " & [Species_BiOP] AS Species, [Year_BiOP] AS obs_year
FROM BiOP_Rec

)  AS sub
GROUP BY sub.Species;
```

When I open it I get a popup asking for a parameter value for Query1.obs_year.  If I just fill in anything and hit okay the table pops up and it works.  I've no idea why this is happening, and the query is not named Query1.

Comment: Is that the entire query?  I've looked at this again and again, and I'm just not seeing anything.  Have you tried creating a separate query that is just the derived table, to see if you get the same error?

Comment: is there a parameter set up?  Sometimes MS Access will automatically create one based on a partial query that then has to be deleted.  Open the query and then click on parameters at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried copying the code into a new query.  I tried compacting an repairing.  I tried saving the database under another name.  Non of which worked.

Eventually I opened the query, switched out of SQL view and into design view, back to SQL view and voila, that appeared to do it.  So strange.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, check your properties, specifically look for references to Queryx in the filter and order by fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and OP solution didn't work for me because the it was caused by something else.
In case someone else is in my condition and stumbles upon this question I'm gonna post cause and solution.
It may be something really basic as I'm a beginner at using Access, but maybe it may help someone out there.

I had a query with both a `GROUP BY` and some calculated column.
something like

```
Select A, B, (A*B) AS C, (A+B) AS D
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B
```

I then added from the design view another calculated field based on C and D and i started getting asked for C and D when running the query.
Looking at the SQL, the design resulted in a wrong query:

```
Select A, B, (A*B) AS C, (A+B) AS D, (D*C) as E
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B, [D]*[C]
```

Notice how the expression was added to the group by?
That's why it was asking for the value when running the query.

SOLUTION

- Remove the unnecessary grouping from the sql

or

- From the design view change the `Total` value of the column from `Group By` to `Expression`